# Remove authentication when deploying a power bi template app with dataverse

Tags: powerbi, publish, dataverse

I am creating a PowerBI Template App, the one which eventually get pushed to "Get App" button, that is using Dataverse as main data source.

When I create the app, I get to the Authentication tab which basically has only one option "OAuth2". When I test it internally, it's fine because I have a user which has access to Dataverse, but I want this app to be available to outside customers and I can't give each of them a user to connect to it.

Is there anyway I can make my report or my app so that it will not require a user to log in ? Otherwise, it means I will not be able to share it to outside user, which pretty much kills the project.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your report to be accessible without authentication, then anyone on the internet who has a link can see it.

If this is fine with you, then you can use [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web) feature

[image: Publish to web (Public)]

Comment: I don't which is the problem. I want to use the email as a filter or something of the sort.
As far as I can tell, there are no easy solution for me so I will have to resort to another way to publish which while fonctionnal, was my plan B. that beind said, that answers my question so you deserves the points.

Comment: I think your scenario is very common, but the solution can't be easy and cheap at the same time. You see, Microsoft did their best to limit scenarios like that implemented easily (and for free), simply because of economic reasons. They are not profitable for them. So you are fighting wind mills here. Even legally, any solution, which would provide your customers with data from dataverse, would legally require a purchase of MS license. As soon as you purchase that, all technical limitations are removed. That's why technical limitations exist in the first place